# How to return from function types when using closures in Go

Tags: go

Im new to GoLang and cannot figure out whats wrong in the code below. What i'm trying to do is "Create and return Printer function on the fly"

```
type Salutation struct {  name string   
    greeting string
}

type Printer func(s string) string

func Greet2(salutation Salutation, do func(string)) (string){
    do(salutation.name + " " + salutation.greeting)
    return "Done"
}

func createPrintFunction(custom string) Printer {
    return func(s string) string {
        return "hello"
    }
}

func pluralSightModule1Closures1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var s = Salutation{"Joe", "Hello"}
    res := Greet2(s, createPrintFunction("!!!"))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write([]byte (res))
}
```

I get the following compilation error

```
 cannot use createPrintFunction("!!!") (type Printer) as type func(string) in argument to Greet2
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `Greet2`.

Comment: @adrian Added Greet2 definition

Comment: `Greet2` takes a `func(string)` as its second parameter, not a `Printer` which is a `func(s string) string`. The types are not the same and not interchangeable.

Comment: I have changed the Printer type to func(string) `type Printer func(string) string`. Same `error`. Also `createPrintFunction("!!!")` is a type of `func(string)`, so the type error doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, `createPrintFunction("!!!")` returns a `Printer`, which is a `func(s string) string`, which is not the same thing as a `func(string)` which is what `Greet2` takes. The return value is significant; `Greet2` takes a parameter with no return value, while `Printer` has a return value of type `string`.

Comment: Got it. I made `Printer` as second parameter to `Greet2`,  `Greet2(salutation Salutation, do Printer)` and it worked.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. One quick question. How do i get return value from `do(salutation.name + " " + salutation.greeting)` in `Greet2`? Instead of returning `Done`, i would like to return the actual value returned?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the signatures don't match. That includes the return type.

`Greet2` wants `func(string)` but `createPrintFunction` returns `func(s string) string`. Note that Greet2's returns nothing, but the `createPrintFunction` function returns a string.

You'll have to decide how to make them match. You probably want to use the return value in `Greet2` for something better than "Done".

```
func Greet2(salutation Salutation, do func(string) string) string {
    return do(salutation.name + " " + salutation.greeting)
}
```

Since you've defined `type Printer func(s string) string` its best to use it consistently to avoid this sort of problem. `Greet2` takes a `Printer` and `createPrintFunction` returns a `Printer`. Then if `Printer` changes things will still work.

```
func Greet2(salutation Salutation, do Printer) string {
    return do(salutation.name + " " + salutation.greeting)
}
```

...but the `do` generated by `createPrintFunction` doesn't use its arguments.  It's hard to advise what it should do because much of this code just passes its arguments straight through, or ignores them.

Anyhow, the signatures have to match.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: @Adrian This is a Question & Answer site. You could have written an answer. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Schwern if you read the comments, you'll see it took some back & forth to arrive at an answer.

Comment: @Adrian It's great that you put in the work, but it didn't result in an answer. The point of the site is to produce good answers that can be voted, edited, and commented on, and so people don't have to wade through comments. No answer camping.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
func Greet2(salutation Salutation, do Printer) (string){
    return do(salutation.name + " " + salutation.greeting)
}

type Printer func(string) string

func createPrintFunction(custom string) Printer {
    return func(s string) string {
        return s
    }
}

func pluralSightModule1Closures1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var s = Salutation{"Joe", "Hello"}
    res := Greet2(s, createPrintFunction("!!!"))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write([]byte (res))
```

}